# Developing A* algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I´m trying to develop a algorithm A* in Python in a recursive way. But it´s not correct because it should have to consider the cost of path and the cost of state. My code is the follow, it gives the right answer but I think it is lucky. Can anybody help fix my code? The total cost is wrong.

```
graph= {'A':{'B':6, 'F':3},
    'B':{'C':3, 'D':2},
    'C':{'E':5, 'D':1},
    'D':{'E':8},
    'E':{'J':5},
    'F':{'G':1, 'H':7},
    'G':{'I':3},
    'H':{'I':2},
    'I':{'E':5, 'J':3},
    'J':{}}

state = {'A':10,
     'B':8,
     'C':5,
     'D':7,
     'E':3,
     'F':6,
     'G':5,
     'H':3,
     'I':1,
     'J':0}
```

[image]

```
def A_star(graph, start_node, end_node, state):
    m ={}
    value = 0
    if start_node == end_node:
        return
    for node, v in graph[start_node].items():
        value = state[node] + v
        m[node] = value 
    if (m != {}):  
        path[min(m, key=m.get)] = value
        A_star(graph, min(m, key=m.get), end_node, state)
    return path


path = {}
path['A'] = 0
bp = (A_star(graph,'A','J',state))

print (list(bp))
print("Total cost: {}".format(sum(bp.values())))
print(bp)
```

> ['A', 'F', 'G', 'I', 'J'] Total cost: 26 {'A': 0, 'F': 9, 'G': 10,
> 'I': 4, 'J': 3}

Comment: This may be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If there is a problem, then you should provide a test case for which it fails. If there is no problem, then the question is off topic here.

Comment: The problem is the total cost that is wrong

Comment: Can you explain your code, or give a link to your reference for A* ? There's a few odd things, like returning the 'path' global variable and not using it, or rebuilding the distance dictionary in every recursive call, that make this an invalid implementation of A*. It's actually performing some kind of greedy depth-first search without backtracking

Comment: (@buran: It is saner to suggest considering a different audience hyperlinking to [their description of their topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - as it happens, this question is off-topic on CR for *code not working[…]as intended*.)

Comment: @greybeard, They claim their code works as intended. And they asked _Can anybory help review my code?_. Note that last sentence _The total cost is wrong_ was added approx. 3 hours after I posted my comment .

Comment: @buran `The total cost is wrong`

Comment: @greybeard, Note that last sentence _The total cost is wrong_ **was added approx. 3 hours after** I posted my comment .

Comment: @user1821998, you seem to be making a recursive call to `A_star`, but not storing/using its return value anywhere.

Comment: Thanks @kiner_shah I think this is an error I didn´t predicted. I would like to thanks the comments and I would like to thanks for the time to help me solving the problem.

Comment: I used the video that explain A* algorithm it is very short but explain in details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vP5TkF0xJgI

Comment: `'G': 10,` should be `'G': 6,` right?

Comment: The video shows that we have to sum the state that is G (5) with the path that is 1 + 3. So what I understand is that it should give 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my code:

```
def backtrace(parent, start, end):
    path = [end]
    while path[-1] != start:
        path.append(parent[path[-1]])
    path.reverse()
    return path


def A_star(graph, start, end, h):
    parent = {}
    queue = {start:h[start]}
    visited = {start:h[start]}

    while queue:

        queueSort = sorted(queue, key=queue.get, reverse=False)
        node = list(queueSort)[0]
        value = queue.pop(list(queueSort)[0])-h[node]

        if node == end:
            return [backtrace(parent, start, end),value]
    
        for i in graph.get(node, []):
            if(i in visited):
                if (visited[i] > value + graph[node][i] + h[i]):
                    parent[i] = node
                    queue[i] = graph[node][i] + value + h[i]
                    visited[i] = graph[node][i] + value + h[i]
            else:
                parent[i] = node
                queue[i] = graph[node][i] + value + h[i]
                visited[i] = graph[node][i] + value + h[i]


bp = A_star(graph,'A','J',state)
print(bp[0])
print(bp[1])
```